# How to send barcode details to database using a php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, barcode

I want to send barcode details to a database using a PHP array and want to create tables in the database according to barcode details. for example;

barcode number: D2D6000001

Here 1st D indicates the product type, 2 indicates production line, 2nd D indicates the month, 6 indicates the year and the last 6 numbers indicate product no.

I want to send each one into separate tables in the database using a PHP array. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: is there any sample code have you tried ? if you have then please post here.

Comment: For better and exact response you should explain with working code snippet here, convenient for all of us

Comment: pls checkout the following link
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112331/inserting-json-array-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below script:

```
<?php
$ReciveBarcode = "D2D6000001";
$GETBARCODE = str_split($ReciveBarcode,5);

$SepratedDetails['productType'] = $GETBARCODE[0][0];
$SepratedDetails['productionLine'] = $GETBARCODE[0][1];
$SepratedDetails['month'] = $GETBARCODE[0][2];
$SepratedDetails['year'] = $GETBARCODE[0][3];
$SepratedDetails['productNumber'] = $GETBARCODE[1];

echo "<pre>";print_r($SepratedDetails);
?>
```

*output:*

```
Array
(
    [productType] => D
    [productionLine] => 2
    [month] => D
    [year] => 6
    [productNumber] => 00001
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using `str_split("D2D6000001")` to split the value to array.
>   You get result some thing like `Array ( [0] => D[1] => 2 [2] => D [3] => 6 [4] => 0 )` .
>   use `substr("D2D6000001",-6)` to get six digit value.